# css compare and output the difference

Tags: css, compare, comparison

I have two similar css files:

- style.css
- style2.css

So these files is long (too much row), and similar, but not the same.

I tried, the total commander, but it's not working, because the css classes stay indiscriminate. I think the correct work should search the class names and every css elements.

I want to compare these files, and I want to get difference to the files, or output.

Do you know software, that made it for me? Or online tool? Or any help for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score -1):

This is not a trivial task, since compare CSS selectors isn't purely syntatical issue. It's related to page organization and so on..